# Anchor back a page and open content

Tags: javascript

My question:
I’m trying to make a jump back to page with anchor work on items that are hidden on a page.
Currently a listing page shows 12 items and more are revealed when clicking button that renders additional rows.

So when a user clicks a business listing below the default 12 items and the user wants to go back, how do I make the page anchor down to the original listing outside of the 12 default items?
Video example:
https://youtu.be/a0IJkJYB4mM

http://newcastlenow-staging.businesscatalyst.com/discover/everything

How do I also automatically open the pagination once the back anchor is implemented?

Comment: You're not really going to be going "back". You need to link back to the original page, but pass a parameter either a # to link to specific content. Or something that will allow your original page to know which record to go back to and display accordingly. Depending on how your data is paginated and displayed on the previous page, this could be rather tricky to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you've got 2 possibilities.

```
1. The browser's History object's native back function
```

For this, you need to set up a button which, on click of course, invokes the following function:

```
window.history.back()
```

Doing so, the browser will go back 1 page, due to its history.

```
2. Custom Link
```

As a 2nd option, you would use a specific link, which would be defined on that button. This would be less dynamic but would lead to the same functionallity, compared to `window.history.back()`.

A short example:

```
<a href="#YOUR_LINK_HERE">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Aer0.
I managed to get that working but how do I automatically open the view more button at the bottom of the list to reveal the tile?

You can see the update on working in this business listing:
http://newcastlenow-staging.businesscatalyst.com/directory/crowne-plaza-newcastle

Comment: Sorry, I really dont get your question right now. What do you want to achieve ... ?

Comment: Oh, now I've got it, after hitting your first link. I guess you want that 'View more' is triggered the moment, you are reaching the end of your current list, instead of clicking on the button. To do so, you need a event listener (e.g. jQueries .scroll()) which constantly checks the position of an element (in this case your View more button), relatively to your document (take a look at jQueries .offset()). Hope this helps.